# Possible to access ASP.NET authorization web service as a JavaScript file?

Tags: asp.net, wcf, asmx

A WCF web service with the right class and method attributes can be accessed as a JavaScript file in a script tag. That is:

```
<script type=".." src="http://someserver/someservice.wcs/js"></script>
```

Is it possible to do the same thing with `System.Web.ApplicationServices.AuthenticationService`?

I'm creating a PhoneGap application developed in static HTML/JavaScript, so I cannot use the script manager.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think you can. see this example on MSDN http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb398896.aspx

Comment: Actually, the example on that page uses the script manager -- unless I messed something.

Comment: @CShipley the example is also available in JavaScript. instead if adding script manager you can also add the MS Ajax Js files which will do the same job